# javascript and html form Checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm wanting to use javascript in my form to make it so that once a checkbox is checked, the other checkboxes in that group are disabled, so a user can only select a maximum of one option.

Here's my html form:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription[]" value="Sweets" id="subscription_1" />
    Sweets
</label>
&nbsp;
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription[]" value="Chocolate" id="subscription_2" />
    Chocolate
</label>
&nbsp;
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription[]" value="Fruit & Veg" id="subscription_3" />
    Fruit & Veg
</label>
```

This is the javascript I'm trying to use:

```
//Check check box
//Script for questions where you check one option or the other (locks other options out)
$(':checkbox').click(function(){ 
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked')

    //If no option is checked, the make all the options available to be selected
    //Otherwise, one option must be checked so lock out all other options
    if(isChecked)
        $checkbox.subscription(":checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else
        $checkbox.subscription(":checkbox").removeAttr("disabled"); 

});​
```

Could someone explain where I am going wrong, please?

Comment: You are using check boxes instead of radio buttons.

Comment: just because i think radio buttons look a bit outdates, personal design choice.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's checkboxes or radio buttons? Sure, it has the functionality the OP wants, but that's not important at all. People have reasons for not wanting something

Comment: Check boxes don't behave like radio buttons because they are not radio buttons. People have expectations about how interface elements will work, and violating those expectations can make your site less usable. I suggest you read http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html

Comment: You're right, we must all conform to exactly what things were meant to be. A lot of things are not what they are being used as anymore. Is a `<ul>` a `<select>` element? No, but it's being used that way for functionality. I still don't see a point in making a fuss about choosing between radio and checkbox. Who's to say what's more "usable". If it accomplishes what the developer wants and it provides something that works on the page, who cares.

Comment: Replacing a SELECT with a UL and a pile of JS will create something that won't show up in a screen reader's forms mode, probably work won't properly with a keyboard, is likely to have issues when used with a touch interface, and so on. Standard UI interfaces inform users how they are expected to interact with them and Just Work across a wide range of different devices (device independence is one of the joys of HTML).

Comment: Rather than disabling the other checkboxes when one is selected why not automatically uncheck any previously checked one when another is selected? That way if the user changes their mind they don't have to first uncheck the current one to re-enable the others but still they'll be able to have at most one checked.

Comment: @Quentin That's not my point at all. That was an example that I've seen used, and isn't important. So many sites/libraries create their own controls out of elements that aren't normally used for their purpose...but it doesn't matter. They're allowed to do whatever they want. What you're saying is basically that the jQuery UI library and almost any other UI library is invalid. A developer can use the datepicker and disable text being typed - that's not standard, and seems "invalid" according to most of these comments, yet I'm sure they still use it.

Comment: @nnnnnn That makes sense to me, and is what I would think is technically the best. But maybe there's a reason why the OP wants it that way

Comment: @ianpgall — Just because other people have done something doesn't mean it isn't a stupid thing to do, or that people shouldn't be warned off it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost what you did :

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    $(':checkbox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

No need to test : disable all and after that enable the clicked one.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5DPrA/)

Note that this UI would probably be disturbing for users : this is not how properly raised checkboxes should behave. For example users will be surprised to have their choice locked at first click.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox').click(function(){
    $checkboxes.filter('[name="' +
                        this.name.replace(/\[/g,'\\[').replace(/\]/g,'\\]') +
                        '"]')
               .not(this).prop('disabled',this.checked);
});
```

That is, retain a reference to all of the checkboxes in a variable (which I've called `$checkboxes`) to save having to create a new jQuery object every time, and then when one is clicked you can disable or re-enable all of the others with the same name by using the `.filter()` method and the [`.not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the current one.

Note also that (unless you're using an old version of jQuery) the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the appropriate way to set the disabled property.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rnbMB/2/

May I suggest though that it would be better for the users if rather than disabling the other checkboxes you simply unchecked them? That way still only a maximum of one could be checked at a time, but users wouldn't have to first uncheck the current one before selecting another:

```
var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox').click(function(){
    if (this.checked)
        $checkboxes.filter('[name="' +
                    this.name.replace(/\[/g,'\\[').replace(/\]/g,'\\]') +
                    '"]')
                   .not(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rnbMB/3/

Of course, either way you need to put that code in a document ready handler and/or in a script block that appears after all of the checkboxes. (A document ready handler might be best since it would keep the `$checkboxes` variable out of the global scope.)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `prop` instead of `attr`

```
 if(isChecked)
    $checkbox.subscription(":checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
else
    $checkbox.subscription(":checkbox").prop("disabled",false);
```